# All folders are Read-Only (Windows)

Tags: windows

This problem has been around for quite some time and I have never found a solution. I even had to format once to get rid of it. And I'm not the only one with this: [here](http://www.trap17.com/index.php/Read-Folders-Xp_t10201.html), [here](http://www.tomshardware.co.uk/forum/page-232514_35_0.html) and here.

Basically, all of a sudden **all folders in my Windows XP setup become (grayed) read only**

[image: Grayed Read-Only]

For many programs this really isn't a big deal. But I found that Eclipse doesn't work anymore!

[image: Eclipse Problem]

- Tried re-installing applications, didn't solve the problem
- [Microsoft's solution](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/256614) doesn't solve the problem
- [Disabling simple file sharing](http://www.askdavetaylor.com/why_is_everything_in_my_documents_marked_read_only.html) doesn't solve the problem
- Changing Read-Only properties to sub-files/folders doesn't solve the problem
- Disabled my antivirus (Comodo Internet Security), didn't solve the problem

There have been [many suggestions if you search](http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=all+folders+read+only&aq=f&oq=&aqi=g1) but none of them worked. This could end up as another Works for Me thing and never be solved.

Comment: The check box is in the third state. There are some (but not all) files/folders that are read only. I've had the case where I can't seem to remove the read-only flag on a file, but I've not investigated further as it's not a problem. Your Eclipse folder is marked read-only - are there any others? Is there a pattern to which folders are read-only? Can you remove the flag from any or none? I know I'm not solving the problem here, but hopefully suggesting an avenue to explore.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Having trouble with Windows XP Read Only Settings on a file](http://superuser.com/questions/20792/having-trouble-with-windows-xp-read-only-settings-on-a-file)

Comment: This is an outstandingly annoying problem. I've seen it in Windows 10. Settings are scattered all over the place and none of them does a thing. At the same time malware infects the system without even noticing these "security" measures. Fixed mine by using a healthy backup...

Answer (score 3):

That doesn't mean what you think it means.  Notice that it's filled with a box rather than a checkmark.  Checkboxes can actually have *three* states: checked, unchecked, and "other".  What you're seeing is the "other" state, and you're seeing it because folders *can't* be marked read-only - there's not read-only bit to set for folders in the first place.

For your specific problem, *permissions* might have changed on the folder.  But that's different than checking the read-only attribute.

Comment: Incorrect. It's a box because of the Windows theme. I've updated the screenshot with the Classic Windows Theme. 

Also, according to this source (mcpmag.com/articles/2006/…), the third state means "What the grayed-out and checked Read-only checkbox is telling you is that subfolders and files of the folder may have the read-only attribute and not the folder itself." or "it may imply that the folder is deemed a “special folder.” For example, folders that support customized views are special folders."

Also, I've made sure about the permissions and ownership. Not solved.

Answer (score 3):

Open and Command Prompt and type in the following command:

```
attrib (drive):\* -r /s
```

Comment: Didn't do anything :(

Comment: So the readonly box is still semichecked?

Comment: Unfortunately, yes...

Comment: I'm having the same problem and when I try this it appears to get "Access denied" for most or all folders. I'm running cmd.exe as administrator.

Answer (score 0):

Hm... if you disabled simple file sharing, did you go into the sharing options and make sure your account has premission to write?

Comment: Yes, I also made sure my account was the owner. For this folder and all sub-files/folders.

Answer (score 0):

You're not copying direct from a CD, are you?  I've seen some "strange" issues with some files coming from CD to disk setting the read-only flag.  The flag is easily cleared for the folder but it's still annoying.

Comment: A) No, even a folder I create is by default read only(!) and B) even if I unset the property it still remains!

Answer (score 0):

I have discovered that saving the documents to almost anywhere but My Documents works. Apparently the problem began after I set up a home network for internet access and printer sharing. I added two users to my wife's computer, one of which has admin rights, making a total of three users, two with admin rights.

Comment: This reply doesn't address the OP's question. And the question itself is based on a mistaken assumption. You should delete your answer.

Answer (score 0):

No idea why Eclipse isn't working for the OP, but the confusion regarding the Read-only checkbox in the file folder Properties dialog needs to be cleared up.

### The Read-only checkbox is not a status indicator!

[image]

Yes, the Hidden checkbox does serve as both toggle & inicator of a folder's Hidden attribute. But the Read-only checkbox, by contrast, is a tri-state *switch*:

- **Checked**: Set attribute on files in folder
- **Cleared**: Clear attribute on files in folder
- **Gray Square**: Take no action

The action (if any) occurs when the **OK** or **Apply** button is clicked.

The "Take no action" state is the default state whenever the **Properties** dialog is displayed --- for every file system folder on every Windows system in the world. Easiest test is to create a new, empty folder & view the dialog. There's the gray square! So much for the mixed content theory!
The way to determine if the Read-only attribute is set for any file or folder is to add the **Attributes** column to a **Details** view in **Explorer**:
[image]