# Not able to uncheck the Read-Only access permission from the folder

Tags: windows-xp

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Windows XP fails to uncheck the Read-only attribute from folder (and subfolders)](https://superuser.com/questions/345027/windows-xp-fails-to-uncheck-the-read-only-attribute-from-folder-and-subfolders)

I am not able to remove the "Read-Only" access permission from the folder.

I tried the following things.

1. Right click on the folder>Properties> unchecked the check box > Apply >ok

   but again its showing Read-Only access in check box.
2. Right click on the folder>Properties>Security

   verify the administrator permissions-->Had the all the accesses
3. cmd > `attrib -r +s C:\Temp`

   It executing with out any issue.

   After this also folder showing "Read-Only" access permission.

Any one please help me how to deselect the "Read-Only" access from the folder.
Venkat

Answer (score 0):

Read-only has not effect on folders. I will assume you are having issues with files in temp.
Also not sure if you meant to set the system attribute(+s). Should use /s to set on current and sub directories.

```
attrib -r -s c:\temp /s
```