# Folder always gets read-only. even when I change it

Tags: windows, read-only

It's the first folder on my hard drive, every other folder works, just this folder gets always read-only. When I untick the option it commits the changes, but is read-only afterwards again?

Comment: please inform us the complete path to the folder

Comment: maybe you have a permission or policy on it?!you can change the owner or permission of your folder first by security tab in properties option and try again !!!

Comment: Folder path is : D:\Games\

Comment: possible duplicate of [Windows XP fails to uncheck the Read-only attribute from folder (and subfolders)](http://superuser.com/questions/345027/windows-xp-fails-to-uncheck-the-read-only-attribute-from-folder-and-subfolders), [All folders are Read-Only (Windows)](http://superuser.com/questions/7989/all-folders-are-read-only-windows)

Answer (score 2):

Is it a folder that has a non-default icon (i.e., something other than the yellow folder, e.g., “My Documents”) or has been customized in some other way?  Windows doesn’t actually support the concept of a folder being read-only at the attribute level (it can, of course, be read-only to some or all users at the security access level).  Instead, Windows uses the Read-only attribute bit on folders to tell Windows Explorer (and, presumably, similar programs) that this folder has been customized, so these programs should look for a hidden `DESKTOP.INI` file in the folder to discover the customization (e.g., what icon to display).

Comment: It's a own created folder. D:\Games\

Comment: Folders are *never* writable. Being able to write to a folder could cause massive chaos and filesystem corruption.

Comment: I think we have some misunderstandings here @DavidSchwartz . The folder has the following field ticked

http://i.imgur.com/BtiewVq.png

And because of that I have to confirm every change as an admin, why?

Comment: @TheoTzaferis: Why do you say "because of that"?

Comment: if you look at the folder properties, and the box is checked, it means that all files within the dir are readonly. if its filled with a box, it means that some are readonly and some aren't. keep in mind though, the read-only attribute is not something that usually requires elevation, unless the user does not have the permission to alter attributes on those objects. also many apps will set a file back to read-only after making a change to it, so you may not be completely able to remove read only from all files. if you continue to have trouble, try the cli cmd 'attrib -r d:\games /s'