# Folder requires admin permissions for every single action

Tags: windows, windows-8, file-permissions

Ok, I already created a [thread](https://superuser.com/questions/577659/folder-always-gets-read-only-even-when-i-change-it/577662?noredirect=1#comment706479_577662) and it said I should visit another thread, and if the problem isn't solved to create a new one with more details. So here I am.

I'm running Windows 8.  I own four hard drives:

- 250 GB SSD (internal)
- 1 TB HDD (internal)
- 750 GB HDD (internal)
- 2 TB HDD (external)

The HDD with the problem is the 1 TB drive. I use this hard drive to install games, save backups and for my Dropbox folder.  The path to the hard drive is D:.

This is the folder structure of the hard drive:

[image]

I'm an Administrator and have Full Permissions to every folder except for `D:\Games`. The context menu of the folders are all identically except for the Games folder.

Normal folder:

[image]

Games folder:

[image: **See Image No. 3**]

I marked the changes in red. The "Elevated permission required" symbol that indicates that I require admin permissions to rename or delete is displayed. The funny part is that I can rename the folder without any problems. I don't get any confirmation dialogue or anything else. I rename the folder and it works without any problems. But, when I want to move something into the Games folder or any sub-folder, I get the following confirmation dialogue:

[image: **See Image No. 4**]

I click Continue and it works, but it's still annoying that I have to do that every time. When I'm in another folder in D:\ I have this options when I want to create something new with the context menu:

[image: **See Image No. 5**]

But in D:\Games I have only the following option:

[image: **See Image No. 6**]

However, when I create a new folder, I don't get a dialogue again. But when I want to delete it, I get the same confirmation dialogue again to confirm, that I'm administrator.

I have no notifications displayed, so it shouldn't be a problem because of that.

[image: **See Image No. 7**]

I already took ownership with this [registry script](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/add-take-ownership-to-explorer-right-click-menu-in-vista/). When I try to do this from the Command Prompt with `takeown /f D:\Games` or `takeown /f Games` I get the following notification:

[image: **See Image No. 8**]

Here is a comparison of the properties of the folders:

**Folder without problems**

[image: **See Image No. 9**]

[image: **See Image No. 10**]

Every group or user name has full control

[image: **See Image No. 11**]

**Folder with problems**

[image: **See Image No. 12**]

[image: **See Image No. 13**]

**Jeder** is translated **Everyone** in English. The rest of the users and groups have full control.

[image: **See Image No. 14**]

I also ran `attrib -r d:\games /s` and this didn't work either. It's annoying and I don't know why it is like this and what to do. Any help?

Comment: Try adding full permissions for a group Everyone (the name will be localized to system's native language).

Comment: I don't know whether to upvote for detail, or downvote for *too much* detail... (went with the upvote)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Click `Enable Inheritance` from the last image. it will get the inheritance rules from the D: drive like the other folder and behave the same. You may need to re-setup your Everyone permission if you do this.

Your other option is add Authenticated Users (Authentifizierbe Bentuzer?) and give them full permissions in addition to the permissions you already have set on the folder.

---

As a P.S. your `takeown` command needs to be run from an administrative command prompt. when you open the command prompt do `Run As Administrator` to open it, that will fix the error message you are getting.

Comment: FWIW, I think "Authenticated Users" is "Authentifizierte Benutzer" in German.

Answer (score 1):

The following steps fixed the problem for me:

1. Right click on the drive and go to Properties.
2. In the Security tab, click on "Advanced"
3. On the top, next to Owner you will see SYSTEM. Click "Change" to change that to yourself so that you are the owner of this drive.
4. In the text box titled "Enter object name to select", enter your user name. To find out your windows user name, open a command prompt window and type "whoami".
5. Finally click Apply.

Answer (score 0):

1. In the *Advanced Security Settings for Games* window select the **jeder** identity ("Everyone" in English, and so on through this post) and then select **Change permission**
2. Select **jeder** again then select **edit**
3. Select **edit** option
4. Enable the **full control** checkbox
5. Click **Apply** and for the settings to be applied
6. Click **OK**