# Most files and all folders have read only permissions

Tags: windows-7, windows, permissions, filesystems, group-policy

I recently installed windows 7 64 bit on a SSD and now, it appears that all of my folders and most of my files are read only. I have tried to remove the read only aspect of them, or take ownership of the drives or folders but I can't seem to have a permanent solution to this issue. I imagine it might have something to do with policies, but I am not familiar enough with them.

Does anyone know how I can fix this?

[image]

Comment: Thank you. I would have done that myself, but I do not have enough reputation score yet.

Comment: If you open properties for single folder, then Explorer always show Read-only attribute in undetermined state regardless of actual state of Read-Only attribute for folder.

Comment: @PetSerAI yeah, So I have read, but I was having issues with some portable apps not being able to save their configuration files.

Comment: But how did you find out that your issues related to Read-only attribute? Even if folder actually have Read-only attribute, it does not prevent to files to be created inside it.

Comment: Because my portable apps are not saving their configurations.

Comment: It is not answer to the question. Why Read-only? Why not file permissions? Why not corrupted file system? Why not something else? How did you find out that Read-only attribute is culprit? What proofs do you have?

Comment: I don't have any proofs. I just want my drives to work reliably.

Comment: It initially did not tell me about that post when I made this one.

Comment: the 'Read Only' checkbox on folder properties has nothing to do with the actual folder. Note that there is a note in parenthesis right next to it that states it affects the files within that tree only.  See: http://superuser.com/questions/866120/cant-remove-read-only-attribute-from-folder-windows-8-1/866147#866147

Answer (score 1):

I ran tweaking.com's permission repair utility. I don't know if that was the problem, but it kind of makes this question invalid. My apologies.

Comment: @agtoever this is the OP's answer to his own question

Comment: @smc this is the OP's answer to his own question

Answer (score 0):

1. Start Registry Editor (Regedit.exe).
2. Locate the following registry key:
   HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Current
   Version\Explorer
3. On the Edit menu, point to New, click DWORD Value, and then type the
   following registry value name: UseSystemForSystemFolders
4. Right-click the new value, and then click Modify.
5. Type 1, and then click OK.
6. Quit Registry Editor.
7. Open a new command prompt as administrator and

   ```
   attrib -r [path you want to change] By exemple :

   attrib -r D:\
   ```

   It will remove the read only attribute.

Comment: I am trying that, but it keeps telling me file not found.

Comment: @RobertHeadley I edited my post to show you the registry thing

Comment: Unfortunately. I can not get that to work either.