# Unsetting read only

Tags: windows-8.1

I have shared folders of Excel files which I can read/write but no one else can write, only read. I have attempted to unset read only to no avail, I have also tried the fix referred to elsewhere on this site, no luck. It's Win 8.1

Comment: To clarify, you've tried:
1. http://superuser.com/questions/20792/having-trouble-with-windows-xp-read-only-settings-on-a-folder
2. http://superuser.com/questions/866120/cant-remove-read-only-attribute-from-folder-windows-8-1
3. http://superuser.com/questions/131119/folder-keeps-changing-back-to-read-only-what-permissions-setup-causes-this-in-w

Comment: I tried number 2

Answer (score 0):

You must explicitly assign read and write permission to users/groups while sharing files/folder as NTFS permissions differ from Sharing permission

[More about sharing files/folders in windows](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-in/windows/share-files-with-someone#1TC=windows-7)

[image: A hint]

Comment: Have done that, no effect whatsoever

Comment: I've done that, the user I have shared the folder with shows read/write permission but still can't make any changes

Comment: All users I have shared with have full permissions but still can't save changes

Comment: file sharing is half the permissions. There's also the security tab. You need to specify the rights there as well.

Comment: @user470145, It seems like a conflict between NTFS permission & sharing permission. Please refer this resource and see what permissions are applied and then proceed  https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc773004(v=ws.10).aspx#BKMK_Shared