# Unable to change Windows file permissions

Tags: windows, windows-vista, permissions, file-permissions, group-policy

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [All folders are Read-Only (Windows)](https://superuser.com/questions/7989/all-folders-are-read-only-windows)

My work computer runs Windows Vista, on a typical Windows network (not sure which version of Windows server).  I am the owner of my documents folder, and I also have admin rights to it.  I am not a sysad, though.

Many of the files in my documents folder are read-only.  I want to be able to change all contents of my documents folder to read/write, but the change does not persist.  When I check the documents folder properties after making the change, the read-only box is still checked.  Is there some other group policy that is preventing me from making this change?

Comment: How are you making the change?

Comment: I am right-clicking on my documents folder to bring up the properties menu.  From there, the read-only box is blue, indicating that subfolders/files are marked read-only.  I have also tried the following from the command prompt:  ATTRIB -R  c:\Users\%username%\Documents\NetBeansProjects /S /D

Comment: It is a duplicate, but of this question: http://superuser.com/q/20792/112868.  Not the one cited.