# Unable to Change Windows Vista Read-Only Folder Attribute

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-vista, permissions

Windows Vista and 7 use the read-only attribute of folders to also indicate that the folder is 'custom.'

It turns out that this is preventing programs I use from updating files in my documents folder.  I am unable to change the read-only setting regardless of whether I right-click on the folder and de-select the read-only checkbox on the properties tab, or if I use the 'icacls' command from the command line.

This has been discussed before by me and others here:

- [Unable to change Windows file permissions](https://superuser.com/q/376543/112868)
- [Having trouble with Windows XP Read Only Settings on a folder](https://superuser.com/q/20792/112868)

However, none of these solutions are working for me.

Has anyone heard of a workaround or solution outside of these links?  Really, all I want to be able to do is use Maven for a software project I'm developing; but my IDE stack (Netbeans 7 & Glassfish 3.x) can't update my project file in my documents folder...  So at the moment I'm stuck using Ant, but I'd really prefer to migrate to Maven.

Here are some links discussing this:

- [You cannot view or change the Read-only or the System attributes of folders](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/326549/en-us?p=1)
- [After XP to Windows 7 upgrade folder stuck in Read Only state](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-security/after-xp-to-windows-7-upgrade-folder-stuck-in-read/be05c603-8a55-4fe6-9335-6fa125d47381?page=2)
- [Resetting NTFS files security and permission in Windows 7](http://lallousx86.wordpress.com/2009/06/14/resetting-ntfs-files-security-and-permission-in-windows-7/)

Comment: Note that this problem represents a bug in your IDE stack; it shouldn't be paying any attention to the folder's read-only flag.  I understand you've got a solution that works for you, but it may still be worth reporting the problem to the relevant developers/vendors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start registery editor (regedit.exe)
 go to the folowing registery key:

> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Current Version\Explorer

Choose in the menu

> edit ->new

and then -> DWORD value with registervalue word

> UseSystemForSystemFolders

click with the right mouse on the new value and click on change Type 1 and click OK
 Close Regedit then you need to do the `attrib -r +s c:\test (where c:\test) is your folder`

Comment: I am already an administrator on my box...

Comment: try this attrib -r +s drive:\<pad>\<foldername>

Comment: The change still doesn't persist.  It goes back to read-only when I reopen the documents folder.   I've also checked for any other group policies, etc.

Comment: Start registery editor (regedit.exe) go to the folowing registery key:HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Current Version\Explorer Choose in the menu edit ->new and then -> DWORD value with registervalue word UseSystemForSystemFolders click with the right mouse on the new value and click on change Type 1 and click OK Close Regedit then you need to do the attrib -r +s c:\test (where c:\test) is your folder.

Comment: link is here: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/256614

Comment: here is another link: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/326549

Comment: changing the registry worked... if you update your answer, then I can accept it

Comment: I've updated my answer

Answer (score 1):

Use the command line:

```
attrib FolderName -r
```

Comment: I tried this, but the change doesn't persist...

Comment: Sorry, made a typo.