# I am trying to remove read only from folder and sub folders with no success

Tags: windows-7

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Unable to Change Windows Vista Read-Only Folder Attribute](https://superuser.com/questions/383952/unable-to-change-windows-vista-read-only-folder-attribute)

I am trying to remove read only from folder by right clicking it,
accepting the "all sub folders" message box but with no success.
any ideas?

Comment: Define "no success" please. Have you tried `ATTRIB -R *.* /S`?

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/383952/unable-to-change-windows-vista-read-only-folder-attribute

Answer (score 1):

Whilst Unlocker will help to achieve the result, possible a better solution is "Take Ownership" , excellent tutorial here:

http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/add-take-ownership-to-explorer-right-click-menu-in-vista/

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using [Unlocker](http://www.emptyloop.com/unlocker/), it's free and very easy to install and good to delete files and folders.