# Folder (contents) Read Only

Tags: windows

Can we revisit the folder (contents) Read Only problem?  On my Win 7 PC, after recovering from a virus, which seems to be gone, all of my folders are gray checked Read Only.  Removing the check mark, saving does not work, it goes right back to Read Only.  Consequently, files can't Unzip, downloads can't install, Save As doesn't do anything.  Temp files can't be created, etc.
The Attribute trick doesn't seem to do anything.  Even Windows can't do some tasks and Explorer will restart after failing to create a temp file.
My PC has only 1 user.
Might this not be a Registry setting?
Has this issue ever been resolved?  I see a lot of posts where it hasn't, so what did everyone do with their PC, toss it?

Comment: The best thing to do after a virus, is to format your drive and rebuild. You honestly can never be **sure** that the virus is gone 100%. Which attribute command did you use?

Comment: `attrib /s /d -r` should recursively remove the read-only attribute from all files and dirs. If that doesn't do it you have other problems. A reinstall might be the best way to ensure a stable and guaranteed clean system.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Folder keeps changing back to read-only. What permissions setup causes this in Windows?](http://superuser.com/questions/131119/folder-keeps-changing-back-to-read-only-what-permissions-setup-causes-this-in-w), http://superuser.com/questions/20792/having-trouble-with-windows-xp-read-only-settings-on-a-file, http://superuser.com/questions/7989/all-folders-are-read-only-windows?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to toss your pc... you can reinstall windows 7 on it! If you've got the drivers cd with you, then just format it (complete format, as quick format won't delete all files).

First take a backup of your files, and folder to a pen drive or cloud. Then format it and install a fresh windows 7. If your pc is 64bit, you'll require a 64 bit win7.... and 64bit drivers. And after installation install an antivirus like AVG or windows own antivirus.

If you don't have the drivers cd, then I'd suggest you download the drivers before formatting and copy them to the pen drive.